# There was problem parsing the package on Samsung s8 any solution for it?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I want to test my **APK** by installing from **Google Drive**, but when i downloads it, it gives me **There was problem parsing the package**  error on **Samsung S8** running **Android 8.1.0(Oreo)**.However for my other **Moto C Plus** running **Android 7.1.0** it installs the app.

I went through App-> three dots -> special access -> unknown apps

and enabled **Allow from this source** for both **Gmail** and **Drive** apps
but it didnt help.

Please help with the solution.

**Thanks** in advance

Comment: try disabling instant run in your app and try again

Comment: @VivekMishra thanks for you answer,But it didnt help

Answer (score 2):

There are several [reasons why this parsing error occurs](https://www.problogbooster.com/2015/09/fix-there-was-a-problem-parsing-the-package-solve-parse-error.html) and definitely one of them is responsible for your parsing error:

1. File may be downloaded incompletely.
2. Application might be not suitable for your hardware or OS version.
3. Due to security issue settings
4. Corrupted APK file.

Make sure the file You downloaded has the same size as original file on Google Drive. If files differ, try to delete downloaded file and download again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @deadfish. Same APK installs fine on my Moto C Plus and not installing it on Samsung S8. I can see a Install button only when APK is fully downloaded.